# Help me find the flaw in my solution to this question on limits?

Tags: calculus, geometry, limits

I am almost embarrassed to ask what seems to me a relatively trivial question here, being a mere amateur self-studying in my spare time. Nonetheless, in the course of my study I attempted to solve the below problem on the topic of limits:

[The problem in question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4rU88.jpg)

Below are the steps I took in an attempt to solve this problem:

Assume PRB and QAB are right angles, otherwise I don't see a way of expressing the problem in terms of a

$$\frac{QA}{PR} = \frac{AB}{RB}$$

(By Similar Triangles)

$$\frac{\theta}{asin\theta} = \frac{OB+a}{OB+acos\theta}$$

$$OB = \frac{a^2sin\theta-a\theta cos\theta}{x-asinx}$$

As theta -> 0,

$$\lim_{\theta\to0} \frac{a^2sin\theta-a\theta cos\theta}{\theta-asin\theta}$$

$$= \lim_{\theta\to0} \frac{a^2cos\theta-acos\theta+a\theta sin\theta}{1-acos\theta}$$ (by L'Hopital)

$$= \frac{a^2-a}{1-a} = -a$$

Which is not what we wanted. I somehow cannot figure out what went wrong. There has to be something stupidly simple I overlooked. Any help much appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  $ \dfrac{a^2-a}{1-a} = \color{red}-a$

Comment: Thanks J.W for spotting that error. I've edited my original post to correct it as my original working didn't reflect that. Still, that leaves us with the question of how to get the desired answer 2a

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You Put $QA = \theta$, but $QA = a \theta$

Comment: Solved. Thank you so much!

Comment: If you found it helpful, please upvote the answer.

Comment: Would if I could. Apparently I don't have enough reputation to upvote.